# Цикл while перечисление строк

Tags: python

Решил сам изучать Python. Вопрос: можно ли реализовать ввод строк через while ?
Хочу ввести определенное количество строк с определенным количеством символов.

Comment: Странный вопрос. Если коротко: да, можно `s = 'xxx'; while s: s=raw_input('-> ')`

Comment: изучать Питон, по одному крайне простому вопросу за раз, не слишком эффективно. И для других людей данная конкретная формулировка может быть не слишком полезна. Попробуйте любую книгу для самых начинающих, незнакомых с программированием прочитать, чтобы обзор получить и простые вещи знать типа: как пользоваться циклом. Имея базу, можно уже самостоятельно пытаться небольшие проекты выполнять.  `while` цикл это не первый выбор для чтения заданного количества строк в Питоне. В чём у вас вопрос: как пример использования while цикла выглядит или как прочитать `n` строк из стандартного ввода?

Comment: @andy.37 ваш код не ограничивает ни число прочитанных строк ни их размер.